# What database technologies do big search engines use?

Tags: database-design, full-text-search

Does anybody knows how Google or Yahoo perform searches for keywords against very very huge amounts of data?  What sort of database or technologies do they employ for this?

It takes few milliseconds, but they have more than a billion pages indexed.

Comment: There is a similar question on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362956/what-database-does-google-use

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I am sure there is a combination of things:

- serious hardware
- lots of it - data is distributed and replicated across many nodes and different data centers

  - (actually in the Google case at least I believe they have thousands and thousands of really low-end servers)
- a lot of common queries' results are cached, notice how they pre-populate potential searches for things you know you've never searched for before; they're predicting what you might search for and hoping they've already got your result pre-calculated and cached somewhere. In a lot of cases they do - there aren't many searches you could come up with on Google today that haven't been asked by someone before you. When they do get a new search phrase then they probably use something like free-text search - and I'd expect keywords are extracted semantically when a page is first crawled rather than trying to find keywords in the document after you've searched for them. Of course they do have to periodically invalidate those caches, re-calculating page rank, and distributing the new cached results across their cache - and I'm sure there's a lot of serious engineering behind that.

Answer (score 34):

**Pigeons**.

The heart of Google's search technology is **[PigeonRank™](https://archive.google.com/pigeonrank/)**, a system for ranking web pages developed by Google founders Larry Page and Sergey Brin at Stanford University:

[image]

> Building upon the breakthrough work of B. F. Skinner, Page and Brin reasoned that low cost **pigeon clusters (PCs)** could be used to compute the relative value of web pages faster than human editors or machine-based algorithms. And while Google has dozens of engineers working to improve every aspect of our service on a daily basis, PigeonRank continues to provide the basis for all of our web search tools.
>
> **Why Google's patented PigeonRank™ works so well**
>
> PigeonRank's success relies primarily on the **superior trainability of the domestic pigeon *(Columba livia)*** and its **unique capacity to recognize objects** regardless of spatial orientation. The common gray pigeon can easily distinguish among items displaying only the minutest differences, an ability that enables it to select relevant web sites from among thousands of similar pages.
>
> By collecting flocks of pigeons in dense clusters, Google is able to process search queries at speeds superior to traditional search engines, which typically rely on birds of prey, brooding hens or slow-moving waterfowl to do their relevance rankings.
>
> When a **search query is submitted** to Google, it is routed to a data coop where **monitors flash result pages at blazing speeds**. When a **relevant result is observed** by one of the pigeons in the cluster, it strikes a rubber-coated steel bar with its beak, which assigns the page a PigeonRank value of one. For each peck, the **PigeonRank increases**. Those pages receiving the most pecks, are returned at the top of the user's results page with the other results displayed in pecking order.

Comment: Note: This page was posted for April Fool's Day - 2002

Answer (score 19):

It's important to bear in mind a couple of things about google:

- Their DB is the proprietary [BigTable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BigTable) - it was custom designed **BY GOOGLE** to exactly fit their needs
- Their proprietary DB is built on top of their proprietary file system - [Google File System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_File_System) - this was designed, again **BY GOOGLE**, to be easily expandable using common commodity hardware.  As Aaron mentioned in his answer, they have a large number of average servers instead of a small number of very powerful servers.

They store individual tables across multiple machines as a way of making access quicker - their software knows which data is on which machine and instead of thrashing through a disk to locate it can go straight to the server with the relevant info.

Answer (score 11):

Google does not use traditional relational database technology. It developed its own technology, big table and map reduce. The original research papers are here : [Big Table](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en//archive/bigtable-osdi06.pdf) and [Map/Reduce](http://static.usenix.org/event/osdi04/tech/full_papers/dean/dean.pdf). Also of interest is the [SSTable, sorted string table](http://www.igvita.com/2012/02/06/sstable-and-log-structured-storage-leveldb/).

Similar tech is now used in [hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) and the [NoSQL databases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL).

Answer (score 9):

Read Steven Levy's "[In The Plex: How Google Thinks, Works, and Shapes Our Lives](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1416596585)".  This book is a fascinating read about all things Google and does discuss at a high level some of the technology and engineering behind search.  Aaron sums it up really well in his answer and Levy's book will give you some more detail about how they do it.