# How Blockchain Databases Work

Tags: storage

I feel like I read somewhere back about blockchain databases but I can't seem to find anything too solid on the topic. [This](http://www.cs.rochester.edu/courses/261/spring2017/termpaper/14/Paper.pdf) paper called *Blockchain Databases* doesn't offer much in terms of description. It is just a few pages, mentioning "Hashchains" and that "Blockchain databases are structured as mutual distributed ledgers (MDLs)", which [doesn't mean much](https://www.bcs.org/content/ConWebDoc/56823).

[This](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1812.02386.pdf) one, *vChain: Enabling Verifiable Boolean Range Queries over Blockchain Databases*, mentions "From the database perspective, a blockchain can be seen
as a database storing a large collection of timestamped data records". They also mentioned [FlureeDB](https://flur.ee/assets/pdf/flureedb_whitepaper_v1.pdf), working on a SQL blockchain database, and [BigchainDB](https://www.bigchaindb.com/whitepaper/bigchaindb-whitepaper.pdf). Both of those projects have little in terms of describing implementation detail on how exactly the "blockchain technology" interfaces with "database". Further, they mention:

> The data stored in the blockchain can be modeled as a
>   sequence of blocks of temporal objects {o1, o2, · · · , on }. Each
>   object oi
>   is represented by ⟨ti
>   ,Vi
>   ,Wi⟩, where ti
>   is the timestamp of the object, Vi
>   is a multi-dimensional vector that
>   represents one or more numerical attributes, and Wi
>   is a
>   set-valued attribute. To enable verifiable query processing,
>   an authenticated data structure (ADS) is constructed and embedded into each block by the miners (to be detailed in Sections 5-7). We consider two forms of Boolean range queries:
>   (historical) time-window queries and subscription queries.

In the FlureeDB paper, it states:

> FlureeDB is a protocol token whose blockchain stores a series of
>   point-in-time facts as atomic units we call Flakes. Every Flake is — and
>   forever will be — unique. Flakes can be thought of as events asserting (or
>   retracting) a fact at a particular point in time. A block is a collection of
>   Flakes as a single atomic transaction, and represents each state change
>   of the blockchain.
>
> ...
>
> Every database is a separate
>   blockchain, and groups of databases are placed into shards
>
> ...
>
> When submitting a transaction, a user will spend their own
>   tokens unless the database has established rules that allow it to spend
>   tokens that it holds. FlureeDB allows a rich permission model that can
>   control exactly what pieces of data can be modified by whom and also
>   which transactions must be paid for by the transacting user. [NOT DESCRIBED]

Still after at least browsing through these papers I don't see any descriptions of how the data storage of database records works in a blockchain / Merkle tree.

My question is specifically, how blockchain applies at the level of storage. I would like to know how the concept of a table, record, column, and value, and relations/links between data, are generally accounted for in a blockchain. That's pretty much the only thing I don't see in any of these resources, how the data model is implemented in the blockchain.

Maybe this [Filecoin paper](https://coinlist.co/assets/index/filecoin_index/Filecoin-Whitepaper-df0c8d36f93bee60ab9a3c7565faece5d37fa615f78a20c7b0e8075686f1ee53.pdf) will be helpful.

Comment: As far as I understand it, a blockchain only guarantees that old values are not tampered with (or if they are, you can detect it). There is no concept of "tables" or "columns" in a blockchain.

Comment: Possibly related: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18700/what-is-a-database